# Loading Wicket Panels dynamically in a <div>

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

In my current Wicket Application I currently make a fullpage reload after the user clicks on one menu item. I want to change this to only reload the necessary Panel.

What I currently do:

I have a `BasePage.html` which contains the menu items and some static content:

```
<li><a wicket:id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a wicket:id="user" href="#">User</a></li>

<!-- and so on ->

<div class="panelarea">
    <wicket:child />
</div>
```

and my (abstract) `BasePage.java`:

```
add(new AjaxSubmitLink("home") {
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        setResponsePage(new HomePage());
    }
});
//etc
```

my `HomePage.html`:

```
<wicket:extend>
    <span wicket:id="homePanel"></span>
</wicket:extend>
```

my `HomePage.java` (and all other Pages) then adds the Panel:

```
add(new HomePanel("homePanel"));
```

Instead of `setResponsePage()` I want to open the Panel in the `<div class="panelarea">` without rerendering the whole page.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: You're already going the way of Ajax it seems, so now you only need to complete that by altering the page's model and telling Wicket what sections to update. The counter example is one of the simplest demonstrations of this: http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/ajaxcounter.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. Make your panel hidden and show it after ajax request
2. Place an EmptyPanel and replace it after ajax request

In both cases, you have to place a placeholder tag in your markup including output markup

```
<span wicket:id="homePanel"></span>
```

**SOLUTION 1: Make your panel hidden and show it after ajax request**

```
final Panel homePanel = new HomePanel("homePanel");
homePanel.setOuputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
homePanel.setOuputMarkupId(true);
homePanel.setVisible(false);
add(homePanel);
add(new AjaxSubmitLink("home") {
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        homePanel.setVisible(true);
        // in Wicket 1.4 instead of target.add(Component)
        // target.addComponent(homePanel);
        target.add(homePanel);
    }
});
```

**SOLUTION 2: Place an EmptyPanel and replace it after ajax request**

```
final Panel emptyPanel = new EmptyPanel("homePanel");
emptyPanel.setOuputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
emptyPanel.setOuputMarkupId(true);
add(emptyPanel);
add(new AjaxSubmitLink("home") {
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        Panel homePanel = new HomePanel("homePanel");
        homePanel.setOuputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        homePanel.setOuputMarkupId(true);
        // if your Page class is MyPage.class
        MyPage.this.addOrReplace(homePanel);
        // in Wicket 1.4 instead of target.add(Component)
        // target.addComponent(homePanel);
        target.add(homePanel);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much! many things about wicket are now a bit clearer to me

Comment: You do not need a `setOuputMarkupPlaceholderTag` if the panel remain visible.

Comment: Also you should use either setOuputMarkupPlaceholderTag or setOuputMarkupId but not both, although it does not make error.

Answer (score 1):

Create a content Panel object for the div you want to replace:

```
 private Panel currentpanel = getHomePagePanel(); // fill it with any Panel you want.
```

You can replace the 'content' panel like so:

```
private void changePanel() {
    Panel newpanel = getNewPanel(); // Or pass as arg to this function
    newpanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    currentpanel.replaceWith(newpanel);
    currentpanel = newpanel;
    target.add(currentpanel);
}
```

Call this within your ajaxlink onSubmit with the correct panel to replace the old one with.